# Insert Value to aspnet_membership table using php

Tags: php, .net, sql, sql-server

I am new to .net and the back end of the website that i have is completed asp.net. I need to use the same mssql database for the front end using php.

You can ask why you should use php and you can use .net for the front end. But i am not familiar with .net. I can access the mssql through php and i can find that the user table is aspnet_membership. I tried to insert a row and it outputs error. there is no mssql_error() function so i don't know what the error is? Through google i can find that the tables are built in with ,net and they have their own stored procedures. Is it still possible to insert it through php? Please help. Thanks

```
$SQL1 = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[aspnet_Membership] ([ApplicationId],[UserId],[Password],[PasswordFormat],[PasswordSalt],[MobilePIN],[Email],[LoweredEmail],[PasswordQuestion],[PasswordAnswer],[IsApproved],[IsLockedOut],[CreateDate],[LastLoginDate],[LastPasswordChangedDate],[LastLockoutDate],[FailedPasswordAttemptCount],[FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart],[FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount],[FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart],[Comment]) VALUES (NULL,'test','test',1,NULL,NULL,'test@domain.com','test@domain.com',NULL,NULL,1,0,'Nov  2 2011 05:54:58:000AM','Nov 14 2011 03:16:21:380PM','Nov  2 2011 03:22:40:627PM','Jan  1 1754 12:00:00:000AM',0,'Jan  1 1754 12:00:00:000AM',0,'Jan  1 1754 12:00:00:000AM',NULL";

$result1 = mssql_query($SQL1) or die('A error occured');
```

**Output: A error occured**

Comment: You'll need to post the code you've tried as well as the error message you encountered, and especially mark the code line number that triggered the error.. it'll help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this. I searched google and found that we can call stored procedures using php. So i just called the asp.net stored procedure and successfully inserted the value. Here is the code

```
$username = "testtest1";
$email = 'phptest1@domain.com';
$pass = 'GreatThing234';
    $sysid = '';

$stmt=mssql_init("[dbo].[p_adduser]", $con) or die("Error");
mssql_bind($stmt, "@Username",    $username,    SQLVARCHAR,    false,  false,  256);
mssql_bind($stmt, "@email",  $email,  SQLVARCHAR, false,  false,  256);
mssql_bind($stmt, "@password", $pass, SQLVARCHAR, false,  false,  256);
mssql_bind($stmt, "@SystemID", $sysid, SQLVARCHAR, false,  false,  256);
$result = mssql_execute($stmt) or die("Error");
```

This above code works for me. Here $con is the mssql connection variable. Thanks